# Alfred: Workflow "Expected end of line" error in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, alfred

I have set up a workflow using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com). The workflow opens a bunch of applications. As a part of this workflow, I also want [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/) to restore the window positions to the preset arrangement I have created.

For [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/), I use the "global" keyboard command <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Å</kbd> to restore the windows. This keyboard shortcut is set in the application's preferences.

I have created this `NSAppleScript` in Alfred:

```
on alfred_script(q)
delay 5
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "Å" using shift down, command down
end tell
activate application "Evernote"
end alfred_script
```

However, I can't get it to work. I'm getting these errors according to the Alfred workflow debug:

```
[ERROR: alfred.workflow.action.applescript] {
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c,\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c,\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {92, 1}";
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keystroke` / `key code` command `using` > 1 modifier keys needs curly brackets:

```
keystroke "Å" using {shift down, command down}
```

↳ [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCECDHC)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually had curly brackets but removed them after seeing some examples where they weren't included. It seems like it's working now!

Comment: There are several ways actually (eg. `option down & shift down`), which is convenient. The `,` was the real issue so unifying shift down with command down is what you want -- the curly brackets work well.